# Batch file to detect when a device connects to hosted wireless hotspot on a laptop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, batch, batch-file

I have created a wireless hotspot on my laptop using:

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

This works perfectly.

I have a raspberry pi that automatically connects to this network automatically, however it takes a fairly random (albeit small) amount of time to connect. Is there a way to pause the batch file until it "detects" the raspberry pi has connected to the hotspot? Or should I simply insert a 60 second pause to ensure it has connected, which would be less ideal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately after further digging I found a solution:

From another thread on stackoverflow... credit to paxdiablo

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set ipaddr=%1
:loop
set state=down
for /f "tokens=5,7" %%a in ('ping -n 1 !ipaddr!') do (
    if "x%%a"=="xReceived" if "x%%b"=="x1," set state=up
)
echo.Link is !state!
ping -n 6 127.0.0.1 >nul: 2>nul:
goto :loop
endlocal
```